# Does there exist a ferromagnetic spin system with all ground states entangled?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, lattice-model, ferromagnetism

Is there a lattice Hamiltonian of quantum spins $H_{\rm goal}(\vec{h})= H_{\rm goal}(\vec{0}) - \sum_i \vec{h} \cdot \vec{S}_i$ satisfying the following two conditions as the number of spins $N$ tends to infinity? I'll take $h \equiv |\vec{h}|$ and $\hat{h} = \frac{\vec{h}}{h}$ in the following.

1. $H_{\rm goal}(\vec{0})$ can have many ground states, but no ground state can be completely unentangled.
2. $H_{\rm goal}(\vec{h})$ has a unique ground state $|g (\vec{h})\rangle$ for $h >0$, and $\lim_{h\to 0} \langle g (\vec{h})| \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \vec{S}_i |g (\vec{h})\rangle = c \hat{h}$ with $c>0$.

Note that by imposing condition $2$, I'm asking that $H_{\rm goal}$ is ferromagnetically ordered; arbitrarily small magnetic fields lead to $O(1)$ magnetization.

---

The reason I ask this question is because of a similar question asked to me by a friend, which led me to the first paragraph of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00812) by Wrzosek et al, which includes the following sentence:

> By contrast, [ferromagnets] can be regarded as more unique because
> their fully polarized ground state does not contain any quantum
> fluctuations, and the low-lying excitations disperse as $k^2$

This got me wondering whether there could be a ferromagnet in the sense of condition $2$ above, for which, in contradistinction to the quote above, all ground states had "quantum fluctuations" in the sense of being entangled.

---

I'm finding it tricky to satisfy both conditions, and it may in fact be impossible. The key challenge is that most (potentially all?) ferromagnets satisfying condition $2$ appear to have the fully-polarized states with maximal $S_{tot}^2$ as ground states of $H(\vec{0})$. This includes the unentangled state $|\uparrow \uparrow .. \rangle$ and more generally all permutation-invariant product states, thus violating condition $1$.

Note that the fully-polarized states, like $|\uparrow \uparrow .. \rangle$, are always eigenstates of $SU(2)$-invariant Hamiltonians, but not necessarily ground states. The trouble is that ferromagnetic systems in the sense of condition $2$ typically do have these maximal $S_{tot}^2$ states as ground states.

---

Here are some additional technical details for the question.

I'm particularly interested in translationally-invariant spin-chains for $H_{\rm goal}$, as I think those would be the most striking examples, but that's not required.

(EDIT: Following the comments, I will require translational invariance rather than having it as a preference.)

It's ok if the ground state of $H_{\rm goal}(\vec{h})$ for $h>0$ is not unique, so long as all of its ground states $|g_n (\vec{h})\rangle$ satisfy $\lim_{h\to 0} \langle g_n (\vec{h})| \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \vec{S}_i |g_n (\vec{h})\rangle = c_n \hat{h}$ with $c_n>0$.

$H_{\rm goal}(\vec{0})$ should be $SU(2)$-invariant, and the range of interactions should be bounded above.

Comment: It seems easy to come up with stupid counterexamples, but I guess you won't like them. E.g. put an antiferromagnetic Heis. chain next to a ferromagnetic one. Or encode the spin-1/2 of your FM chain in a subspace of the full local Hilbert space (e.g. by putting some terms on two or thee or so spin 1/2), such that the effective spin-1/2 space consists only of entangled states.

Comment: Does this not work for a simple ferromagnet with $H = - J \sum_j (Z_j Z_{j+1} + g X_j + h Z_j)$? The entangled ground states for $h=0$ are the ± combinations of all up and all down, but $h>0$ picks all up, e.g., which is not entangled (and unique). For large $g$, you have paramagnetic states (also unique GS). Or does this fail somehow?

Comment: @justaphase Thanks, but I allow any direction for the field, and yours is only a ferromagnet in the $Z$ direction. More specifically, I take it your $H(0) = - J \sum_j (Z_j Z_{j+1} + g X_j)$;  $H(h \hat{y}) = - J \sum_j (Z_j Z_{j+1} + g X_j + h Y_j)$ does not have $O(1)$ magnetization in the $y$ direction for arbitrarily small $h$. Yours is also ruled out because it doesn't have $SU(2)$ invariance. Happy to talk more in chat if you have any questions.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks. Your guess is right :). I'm going to add some things to my question to rule your first example out, like making my preference for translational invariance a requirement (to avoid having two uncoupled chains). I could see something nice from the embedding - you wrote a very nice answer with isometries for constructing a zero-correlation length state in the Haldane phase. I'm not sure I fully understand your construction here, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Well, it might also break translational invariance ... though it might be possible to avoid this. The idea would be to have one strong local (say, 3-site) term in the Hamiltonian whose ground space is 2-dimensional. Then you add further terms, which in perturbation theory implement a Heisenberg Hamiltonian on said 2-dim. spaces. Then, within those 3 sites the state will be entangled. --- Regarding tinv. examples, I would suspect that one can build something based on translational invariant QMA constructions.